# "Swift_TransportException Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0]" on localhost

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, smtp

I got the issue below:

> Swift_TransportException
>   Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0]

when sending mail in Laravel on localhost but work perfectly on online server.

Tried many tricks and solutions but no success. Can anyone help on this issue?

My `.env` file looks like this:

**.env**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=XXXXXX@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD="**********"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Comment: and what were those tricks you tried? so we don't all have to waste time reiterating all those tricks, as this has come up many many times

Comment: change your port => 587

Comment: Port change, less secure app enable, firewall off, antivirus disabled.

Comment: Tried with 587 already, no success.

Comment: Tried with `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tsl`?

Comment: don't go for less secure , password you use is your mail password or app password?

Comment: Also tried tls and got "Swift_TransportException
Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message "" ". @HimanshuUpadhyay

Comment: I think it's not about password or account because same configurations working ok on live server hosted. @GauravGupta

Comment: There are number of reasons this could go wrong but I strongly suggest you to use mailtrap free account and keep the default smtp settings. This will defnitly work on your localhost and you will avoid sending the email to wrong users as well.

Comment: @Suraj can you please tell me how to use mailtrap? what is there mail_host, port etc?

Comment: Just signup for mailtrap.com and once you login you will get the all the smtp details. Like host, password, username etc.

Comment: This might help you to setup. http://www.codebyjigs.com/safe-email-testing-laravel-mailtrap/

Comment: @Suraj Thanks. It worked.

Comment: @AnsibRaza Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

don't use your gmail password instead of that you can generate app password in gmail use that also don't go for less secure

here how's your env look like

```
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=examle@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=somestringbygmail
```

generate your app password by visting [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en)

Comment: Tried but same issue. Work for live server but not for localhost :(

Comment: with app password ?

Comment: driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'ssl'),     'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),   'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'example@gmail.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'ABC'),
    ],

Comment: kindly  plz update acc to this
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => ['address' => "example@gmail.com", 'name' => 'test'],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',